# Handling multiple intent call

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using an explicit intent to pass a message from my App1 to another one of my apps, App2.
It is working nicely with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("mypkg","mypkg.myactivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("Key1", "MyCustomValue1");
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I would like to send follow up message via intent (after the initial intent is sent), but once App2 is up and I send the follow up intents, the onCreate() in App2 is not hit again.  So, how can I get it so that I can send multiple intents to App2 and capture each one in App2 ?

(Yes, I know a service would be better here, but this design is outside the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but once App2 is up and I send the follow up intents, the onCreate() in App2 is not hit again

They are being delivered to `onNewIntent()` in your activity instance.

> Yes, I know a service would be better here

Or possibly an event bus, like greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, or Square's Otto.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.
BTW - I had to add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag on the subsequent intent calls to get the onNewIntent() to fire.